# Why do I have an A record pointing to an IP of a namecheap server?

Tags: dns, namecheap

From what I understand an A record maps a domain name to an IP of a machine that serves content/provides API.
When I look up my DNS records I get two A records. One points to my machine and another one points to an IP belonging to Namecheap company ([ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io/192.64.119.107)). The second A record is not shown in the "Advanced DNS" panel on their website in my account, so I can't delete it. Why do I have the second A record? What is the point of it?

Comment: This question is more suitable for [su], as it is not a programming related question.

Comment: @KenWhite, thank you, sir! I'll head there the next time! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. In admin panel on **namecheap.com** I added redirects, so that when a user types `example.com` their browser redirects them to `https://example.com`.
In the DNS system there's no special records that handle redirects like that, so a company like **namecheap** adds an A record and points it to its own dedicated server that redirect users to a destination point in my case `https://example.com`